# Changing rows and columns by order when the identifications are different for different pairs/dyads

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-wrangling

The aim is to swap the rows and columns, while making the columns in the order of the numerical value of the identifications. For example, the data I have look like:

```
structure(list(pair_id = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "12_34   ", class = "factor"), 
    member_id = c(34, 12), trait1 = c(5, 2), trait2 = c(3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), variable.labels = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L)
```

Visually, the above looks like:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ pair_id ║ member_id ║ trait1 ║ trait2 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  12_34  ║     34    ║    5   ║    3   ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  12_34  ║     12    ║    2   ║    3   ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

In swapping 'member_id' and 'trait1-trait2', I'm looking for a way to make sure that the traits also are structured in the order. That is, the expected end result would be:

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ pair_id ║ trait  ║ member1 ║ member2 ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  12_34  ║ trait1 ║    5    ║    2    ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  12_34  ║ trait2 ║    3    ║    3    ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wont need the group_by() for this specific example but you will once you have more than one pair_id, which I am assuming your dataset will have.

```
df <- structure(list(pair_id = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "12_34   ", class = "factor"), 
               member_id = c(34, 12), trait1 = c(5, 2), trait2 = c(3, 3)), class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
               variable.labels = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L)

df %>%
  arrange(member_id) %>%
  group_by(pair_id) %>%
  mutate(member_id = paste0("member",row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gather(trait, value,-c(1:2)) %>%
  spread(member_id, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`, we can use `melt` and `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = c('trait1', 'trait2')), 
     pair_id + variable ~ paste0('member', rowid(variable)), value.var = 'value')

#    pair_id variable member1 member2
#1: 12_34      trait1       5       2
#2: 12_34      trait2       3       3
```